# Checkout or list remote branches in GitPython

Tags: python, git, gitpython

I don't see an option to checkout or list remote/local branches in this module: https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After you’ve done

```
from git import Git
g = Git()
```

(and possibly some other command to init `g` to the repository you care about) all attribute requests on `g` are more or less transformed into a call of `git attr *args`.

Therefore:

```
g.checkout("mybranch")
```

should do what you want.

```
g.branch()
```

will list the branches. However, note that these are very low level commands and they will return the exact code that the git executables will return. Therefore, don’t expect a nice list. I’ll just be a string of several lines and with one line having an asterisk as the first character.

There might be some better way to do this in the library. In `repo.py` for example is a special `active_branch` command. You’ll have to go through the source a little and look for yourself.

Comment: when i run r = Git.clone("git ...")  r.checkout("develop")  does not work.. AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'checkout'

Comment: ok looks like I need to run a g = Git("dir") then I can checkout

Answer (score 19):

For those who want to just print the remote branches:

```
# Execute from the repository root directory
repo = git.Repo('.')
remote_refs = repo.remote().refs

for refs in remote_refs:
    print(refs.name)
```

Answer (score 17):

To list branches you can use:

```
from git import Repo
r = Repo(your_repo_path)
repo_heads = r.heads # or it's alias: r.branches
```

`r.heads` returns `git.util.IterableList` (inherits after `list`) of `git.Head` objects, so you can:

```
repo_heads_names = [h.name for h in repo_heads]
```

And to checkout eg. `master`:

```
repo_heads['master'].checkout() 
# you can get elements of IterableList through it_list['branch_name'] 
# or it_list.branch_name
```

Module mentioned in the question is `GitPython` which [moved](http://web.archive.org/web/20130526031116/http://gitorious.org/git-python) from `gitorious` to [Github](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython).

Comment: Looks like its documented here: https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html?highlight=branch#git.repo.base.Repo.branches

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue. In my case I only wanted to list the remote branches that are tracked locally. This worked for me:

```
import git

repo = git.Repo(repo_path)
branches = []
for r in repo.branches:
    branches.append(r)
    # check if a tracking branch exists
    tb = t.tracking_branch()
    if tb:
        branches.append(tb)
```

In case all remote branches are needed, I would prefer running git directly:

```
def get_all_branches(path):
    cmd = ['git', '-C', path, 'branch', '-a']
    out = subprocess.check_output(cmd, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    return out
```

Comment: If you already have a Repo instance, you can call git commands directly as: ```repo.git.branch('-a')```

Answer (score 4):

Just to make it obvious - to get a list of remote branches from the current repo directory:

```
import os, git

# Create repo for current directory
repo = git.Repo(os.getcwd())

# Run "git branch -r" and collect results into array
remote_branches = []
for ref in repo.git.branch('-r').split('\n'):
    print(ref)
    remote_branches.append(ref)
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, with GitPython, if you know how to do it within command line, but not within the API, just use repo.git.action("your command without leading 'git' and 'action'"), example: git log --reverse => repo.git.log('--reverse')

in this case https://stackoverflow.com/a/47872315/12550269

So I try this command:

```
repo = git.Repo()

repo.git.checkout('-b', local_branch, remote_branch)
```

this command can make a new local branch name `local_branch`(if already haved, rasie error) and set up to track remote branch `remote_branch`

it works very well!

Answer (score 0):

I took a slightly different approach here, based on the desire to obtain a list of branches that can be checked out:

```
repo = git.Repo(YOUR_REPO_HERE)
branch_list = [r.remote_head for r in repo.remote().refs]
```

Unlike the answer using `refs.name`, this obtains the name without the remote prefix, in the form you would want to use to check out the repository.