# Unable to clone or fetch all the branches using git python

Tags: python, git, gitpython

I have been trying to clone all the branches of the repository using python, but it is showing just the default branch not the feature branch which is there.
Below is the code

```
    import git
    from git import Repo
    repo = git.Repo.clone_from(url,dir_path)
    repo.remotes.origin.fetch() //Approach 1
    for remote in repo.remotes: //Approach 2
       remote.fetch()
```

I want to achieve git fetch --all with all remote branches. please suggest

Comment: This answer lists how to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42214587/4332397

Comment: It is not showing me all the branches.Shows only default branch

Comment: repo = Repo.clone_from(parsedurl,clonedir). This solved my problem