# How to create a new local branch using GitPython?

Tags: python, git, gitpython

I want to create a new branch using GitPython. I usually use the following git command for the same:

Git command:

```
git checkout -b feature/test-git-python
```

Code:

```
from git import Repo

PATH_TO_REPO = XXXX

repo = Repo(PATH_TO_REPO)
repo.git.stash()
repo.git.checkout('master')
repo.git.checkout('-b feature/test-git-python')
```

Error:

```
git.exc.GitCommandError: Cmd('git') failed due to: exit code(128)
  cmdline: git checkout -b feature/test-git-python
  stderr: 'fatal: ' feature/test-git-python' is not a valid branch name.'
```

This is the error I am getting. I assume it's taking the space before the branch name into consideration.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check out a branch with GitPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47872070/how-to-check-out-a-branch-with-gitpython)

Comment: @Eugenij Yes, it does. Thanks.